# c++ why return a reference to a base abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, abstract-class

In the class below there is a pointer `model_` of type `OpModel` which is a class. This pointer is initialized in the constructor using `new` to create an `OpModel` object. That's fine, you have a pointer to a valid object. The method `model()` deferences this pointer which access the actual `OpModel` object. But what I don't understand is that it returns a reference to `CompositionalModel` which is a different class.

I believe that it is related to polymorphism because `OpModel` is derived from `CompositionalModel`, which is an abstract class. But why would you return a reference to the base class?

Comment: Hopefully, whatever book/site you're using will get you where smart pointer (or no pointer) are the flavor of the day. That aside, yes, it's an OOP thing.  the answer below is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a typical thing to do in OO code.

By returning the narrower, base class - think interface - the calling code need only know aboout that.
You can hide all kinds of extra gory, implementation details that way.
Otherwise, any calling code needs to know all about `CompositionalModel`.

Furthermore, this can change the `OpModel` to any other type of `CompilationUnit` and the calling code won't need to change.